# breaking out of for loop for first calculator

Tags: android, android-studio

To qualify this question, I am a newb at coding and making a calculator in order to familiarize myself with Android Studio. So that's also why the code looks incomplete. I am currently testing it with just the numbers eight and nine and the plus sign.

My question is how do I break out of this for loop after clicking the plusBtn such that the number inputs go to the second text view? If there is a better way than using a for loop than that is fine as well.

```
package com.example.calculator3;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button num9;
    private Button num8;
    private TextView firstNumber;
    private TextView relation;
    private TextView secondNumber;
    private Button plusBtn;
    private TextView result;
    private Button equalsBtn;
    //private double val1;
    //private double val2;
    // private final char ADDITION = '+';
    //private final char EQUALS = '=';
    // private char ACTION;
     //public boolean isPlusClicked = false;
     //String relationStr = relation.getText().toString();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        num9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.num9);
        num8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.num8);
        firstNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
        relation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.relation);
        secondNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondNumber);
        plusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plusBtn);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        equalsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equalsBtn);


        if (relation.getText().length() == 0){
            num9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    firstNumber.setText(firstNumber.getText().toString() + "9");
                }
            });
            num8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    firstNumber.setText(firstNumber.getText().toString() + "8");
                }
            });

            plusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    relation.setText("+");

                }
            });

        } else {

            num9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    secondNumber.setText(secondNumber.getText().toString() + "9");
                }
            });

            num8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    secondNumber.setText(secondNumber.getText().toString() + "8");
                }
            });

            plusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    relation.setText(relation.getText().toString() + "+");

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/num9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="152dp"
        android:text="9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/num8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
        android:text="8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plusBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
        android:text="+"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/result"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/num8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.518"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/num9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/equalsBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="="
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/plusBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/secondNumber" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="firstNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/relation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="184dp"
        android:hint="relation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstNumber" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:hint="secondNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:hint="result"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

'''
```

Answer:

```
'''
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button num9;
    private Button num8;
    private TextView firstNumber;
    private TextView relation;
    private TextView secondNumber;
    private Button plusBtn;
    private TextView result;
    private Button equalsBtn;

    //private double val1;
    //private double val2;
    // private final char ADDITION = '+';
    //private final char EQUALS = '=';
    // private char ACTION;
     //public boolean isPlusClicked = false;
     //String relationStr = relation.getText().toString();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        num9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.num9);
        num8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.num8);
        firstNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
        relation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.relation);
        secondNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondNumber);
        plusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plusBtn);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        equalsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equalsBtn);



        num9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (relation.getText().length() == 0) {

                    firstNumber.setText(firstNumber.getText().toString() + "9");
                } else {
                    secondNumber.setText(secondNumber.getText().toString() + "9");
                }
            }
        });

            num8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (relation.getText().length() == 0) {

                        firstNumber.setText(firstNumber.getText().toString() + "8");

                    } else {
                        secondNumber.setText(secondNumber.getText().toString() + "8");
                    }
                }
            });

            plusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (relation.getText().length() == 0) {
                        relation.setText(relation.getText().toString() + "+");

                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To attempt to move the user "focus" to a new view element, use that view's `requestFocus()` method:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus()

One quick note, since you posted your code here. The onCreate method is being called when the app starts. It is not a loop and not called after each button push, so you need to move some things around.

When this is called, there is never anything in the first input, so half of these click events are never set up. Instead of

> onCreate
>
> if(relation.getText().length() == 0)
>
> > set all of the event listeners (but now they only ever work with the first input!)

you need to organize it so that you are making this check within EACH of those event listeners. Good luck!